# How to test React.js page that uses Context and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I'm having trouble testing a page that has Context and useEffect using Jest and Testing-library, can you help me?

REPO: https://github.com/jefferson1104/padawan

**My Context**: src/context/personContext.tsx

```
import { createContext, ReactNode, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { api } from '../services/api'

type PersonData = {
  name?: string
  avatar?: string
}

type PersonProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode
}

type PersonContextData = {
  person: PersonData
  loading: boolean
  handlePerson: () => void
}

export const PersonContext = createContext({} as PersonContextData)

export function PersonProvider({ children }: PersonProviderProps) {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState<PersonData>({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()

  function checkAvatar(name: string): string {
    return name === 'Darth Vader'
      ? '/img/darth-vader.png'
      : '/img/luke-skywalker.png'
  }

  async function handlePerson() {
    setLoading(true)
    const promise1 = api.get('/1')
    const promise2 = api.get('/4')

    Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then(function (values) {
      const data = {
        name: values.data.name,
        avatar: checkAvatar(values.data.name)
      }

      setPerson(data)
      setLoading(false)
      router.push('/battlefield')
    })
  }

  return (
    <PersonContext.Provider value={{ person, handlePerson, loading }}>
      {children}
    </PersonContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**My Page**: src/pages/battlefield.tsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { PersonContext } from '../context/personContext'
import Person from '../components/Person'

const Battlefield = () => {
  const { person } = useContext(PersonContext)
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!person.name) {
      router.push('/')
    }
  })

  return <Person />
}

export default Battlefield
```

**My Test**: src/tests/pages/Battlefield.spec.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

import { PersonContext } from '../../context/personContext'
import Battlefield from '../../pages'

jest.mock('../../components/Person', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: function mock() {
      return <div data-test-id="person" />
    }
  }
})

describe('Battlefield page', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const mockPerson = { name: 'Darth Vader', avatar: 'darth-vader.png' }
    const mockHandlePerson = jest.fn()
    const mockLoading = false

    render(
      <PersonContext.Provider
        value={{
          person: mockPerson,
          handlePerson: mockHandlePerson,
          loading: mockLoading
        }}
      >
        <Battlefield />
      </PersonContext.Provider>
    )

    expect(screen.getByTestId('person')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

**PRINSCREEN ERROR**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0mvl.png)

Comment: it seems like your mock for Person component was not successful, as the output in your image also shows things not in the code shown. Can you either make sure Person is mocked correctly or write this test against the actual Person component?

Comment: Resolved, the error was happening because the path where I call the Battlefield page didn't have the absolute path

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

The error was happening because the path where I call the Battlefield page didn't have the absolute path.